# What browser engine does Android use for phonegap?

Tags: css, cordova

I'm trying to implement some CSS animations in a phone gap project. The animations run fine on an iOS device but not on my Android. In fact some things like dashed borders aren't even rendering.

Do I need any special vender prefixes for Android within a phonegap project?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PhoneGap uses native browser engines. So in android, it uses WebKit.

From [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/2012/05/02/phonegap-explained-visually/)

> web view used by PhoneGap is the same web view used by the native
>   operating system.On iOS, this is the Objective-C UIWebView class; on
>   Android, this is android.webkit.WebView.Since there are differences in
>   the web view rendering engines between operating systems, make sure
>   that you account for this in your UI

This [tutorial](http://borishoekmeijer.nl/how-to-target-a-specific-browser/) may be helpful for you. It shows how to target for specific browser(means specific render engine).

Hope this helps!

Comment: So wouldn't it make since that the -webkit prefix that works in iOS work on Android? I'm at a loss as to why there's such a discrepancy.

Comment: Though both iOS and Android uses WebKit, they render differently. Here is a list of differences you may find useful http://quirksmode.org/webkit_mobile.html. But guys in these website claim that there is no difference: http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2603-heres-what-weve-learned-about-doing-ui-for-mobile-web-apps-with-html5

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because it did help me find what was happening. It turns out it was the custom ROM I had on my Android Phone. I loaded my project onto a stock Nexus 7 and it worked great including the CSS animations.

Answer (score 3):

Take care because [since version 4.4](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html) (only) Android does use a Chromium based webview (I think before it was simply a webkit-based webview).

The WebView prior to 4.4 has a bad reputation as far as I've read.

This is another reason to use the [Crosswalk project](https://crosswalk-project.org/) which has a Cordova plugin and permits to embed a specific version of Chromium, so that all your apps are using the same WebView engine no matter the SDK (a a cost of a big APK)

Comment: Unfortunately, the Crosswalk project is currently unmaintained.