# Which underlying Browser does PhoneGap use on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

Since PhoneGap runs an html page in a native app container, I suppose I require some kind of browser to do that.

**Which underlying Browser does PhoneGap use on Android? Is it the default installed browser or does phonegap has its own? Or is it Chrome?**

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069761/what-browser-engine-does-android-use-for-phonegap

Answer (score 1):

Phone Gap (Cordova) currently uses the standard Android WebView which is a stripped down version of a browser (based on a particular version of WebKit).

It can't really be the Chromium-based WebView yet, that was just [made available](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview) as a component to third party developers only recently in Android 4.4.

And as of April 1st 2014, Android 4.4 (KitKat) constitutes only about 5.3% of [all the Android versions](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) (not to mention, this new Chromium-based WebView still seems to be a work in progress, so it will take a while for most third party developers to feel completely comfortable with it).

[image]

Comment: The Chromium Based WebView is based on Chrome/30, and has numerous basic bugs that interfere with simple things such as key events.  This has led to all new frustration with number masking on fields and JS Autocomplete being completely broken.  We are working on making the webview configurable so that you can use third-party webviews with Cordova instead of the stock browser, however this will most likely only work on ICS and higher, if not Jellybean and higher.  For right now, we're stuck with what's on the device.

Comment: There are alternatives to PhoneGap Cordova. Are those alternatives any good? That depends on your requirements. Also, that depends on who you ask. Me, I'm a Java Android developer, so I'm partial to Java and only Java on Android. Ask a Phone Gap developer, or a Sencha Touch developer, or a Titanium developer, or an Adobe Flex developer, and you'll probably get a very different answer from each.