# How does PhoneGap's tech stack differ in Development vs Production Mode

Tags: cordova

My *understanding* is that PhoneGap/Cordova is an SDK/CLI that gives you a consistent API **at the JS layer** for accessing hardware/OS features on native devices. Hence, I could use the PhoneGap CLI to install the "Device Motion" plugin and then have access to the onboard accelerometer like so:

```
// Inside some JavaScript
navigator.accelerometer.getCurrentAcceleration(accelerometerSuccess, accelerometerError);
```

...and, furthermore, I can rest assured that if this code is running on a native (PhoneGap-compatible) device that has an accelerometer on it, that my code should work universally, across the board. Pretty sweet.

So I took PhoneGap for a test spin and followed their [*Get Started* guide](http://phonegap.com/getstarted/) and got it working. The TL;DR there is that you end up with the ability to make changes to code running on your laptop and see them get uploaded in real-time as hot changes to an app running on your mobile device. Even sweeter!

But all this has me wondering: what's really going on under the hood here? So you have this "**Development Mode**" where:

1. You start running PhoneGap on your dev machine/laptop
2. You start running PhoneGap on your mobile device, and then give it the the correct URL to connect to (of some PhoneGap agent running on your dev machine)
3. Now you can hot deploy changes to your mobile device for quick dev/test cycles

But on the other hand you *must* (I assume, at least, haven't gotten this far yet) have a "**Production Mode**" whereby:

1. You are happy with your changes from *Development Mode*
2. Now you want to package/bundle your app as a native binary for all supported platformed (or at least the ones you are choosing to support)
3. For each native binary, you deploy it to its respective marketplace/app repo (where people in the real world can download it)

So I guess I'm confused about *what is actually running on my mobile device during Development Mode* vs *what PhoneGap uses to produce the native binaries during Production Mode*. In order for a browser to parse and render HTML/CSS/JS, it needs engines/interpreters inside of it to get the job done. Does PhoneGap ship with its own HTML/CSS/JS interpreter? If not, what does the tech stack look like when its running in Development Mode, and how does that tech stack look different for the native binaries it produces during Production Mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does PhoneGap ship with its own HTML/CSS/JS interpreter?

No, actually Cordova is using **the system browser** (or more precise its [WebView](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/what-is-a-webview/)) to render HTML and run JS, as you can see in the architecture overview (Source: PhoneGap for Enterprise by Kerry Shotts). So the utilized browser depends on your devices OS: On iOS it would be Safari for example. See another question on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069761/what-browser-engine-does-android-use-for-phonegap) or this pretty informative [blogpost](http://phonegap.com/blog/2012/05/02/phonegap-explained-visually/) for further info.

[image: Cordova architecture]

> But on the other hand you must (I assume, at least, haven't gotten this far yet) have a "Production Mode"...

You're right, after developing you have to package and publish your app. As you mentioned this is something you'll have to do for each platform you support and the process is not quite the same, so I'll not go into detail here. It boils down to **building a package** like an apk for Android or an ipa for iOS, **signing it** and **publishing it** in the corresponding store.

Microsoft offers a little more detail on how to publish your app for the major platforms with Visual Studio [here](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-package-publish-readme/).

Comment: Thanks @Phonolog (+1) - a few quick followup questions if you don't mind: (1) So if I understand your answer correctly, then when I am running the app locally in "Development Mode", then is PhoneGap actually spawning an instance of my system browser for the actual rendering of the app (in my case it would be Safari)? And (2) if that's correct, then what happens when I switch to "Production Mode" and build an Android apk and push that to the Android marketplace? If a user runs my app, are they actually still viewing my app through their device's system/default browser? Thanks again!

Comment: Yep that's about it. In both cases you create an app (or use the developer app) to render your HTML & CSS in a webview of the systems default browser. If your testing on an iPhone/iPad this would be a Safari webview then. If someone downloaded your app from the Google playstore and installed it on his Android phone he will be viewing your HTML & CSS in a Chrome webview (or the old Android browser). So the big deal about Cordova is that pretty much every platform has a browser, so (theoretically) you can run your code everywhere. Hope this helps ;)